# When Enter is pressed Ok Button should be clicked

Tags: c#, wpf

When enter key is pressed the OK button should be clicked no matter where is the focus on the control.

Comment: You can set the isDefault property of button to make it default button and whenever enter is pressed it wil be called

Comment: We need to see the code you are using, at the very least, to understand what you are doing, why you are doing it *that* way and *how* it fails.

Comment: @Arran : i am doing on the UI not by code

Comment: It depends on the control. When a multiline textbox has the focus, Enter should NOT press the OK button.

Comment: isDefaultProperty we have to set by code or by property window

Comment: @Saminzz see my answer below.

Comment: Thanks for the help but help me for winform also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the [isDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.isdefault.aspx) property of Button.

something like

```
<Button Name="btnDefault" IsDefault="true" Click="OnClickDefault">OK</Button>
```

For windows Form it is called as AcceptButton. see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks its working .. and plz also tell me how to perform the same operation in winforms

Comment: thanks i cleared all ma doubt

Answer (score 1):

Buttons have a property `IsDefault` and `IsCancel` they correspond to the Enter and Escape key respectively. So you can set them like so:

```
<Button Content="OK" Command="{Binding OKCommand}" IsDefault="True" />
<Button Content="Cancel" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" IsCancel="True" />
```

Comment: thanks its working i got to now

Answer (score 0):

set "IsDefault =true" inXAML file

```
<Button Name="btnName" IsDefault="true" Click="OnClick">OK</Button>
```

see [**Accept button**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

```
form1.AcceptButton = button1;
```

Comment: thanks plz help me also to do the same in winforms